# Beginner Learning Material

Tags: network-discovery

I want to begin to learn about the basics of networking.  Is there any networker's 'bible' or high regarded very entry level reading material I can begin to read?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions about product or resource recommendations are specifically off-topic.

Comment: Really? Resource recommendations too?  Because it would be helpful and I'm sure this community can very quickly and easily provide some insightful answers.

Comment: From the Help Center: **Off-topic: Product or Resource Recommendations**

Requests for product recommendations, resource recommendations, or polls are off-topic.

However, polls and recommendations are welcome in the Network Engineering Recommendations Chat Room.

Answer (score 2):

Cisco CCNA Exploration 4.0 is the best that you can find, where are explained on a easily way, all the basics topics of networking